# BizTalk ESB 2.1 - Right message, wrong message type

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.0

I have a request/response itinerary made up of orchestration extenders.  Everything works fine including the message sent back to the web service.  However in the receive port there is an outbound map that never gets fired.  I have tracked this down to the fact that the message, although correct, has the wrong message type context.  Infact it has the context of a message a few steps back in the itinerary.  Why is this and how can I solve the issue?

BTW I have tried changing the context in a pipeline component followed by the ESB transform component to no avail.

Comment: (I haven't used ESB) How are you transforming the message to a different type? Is it done in the extender? That sounds like why/where you didn't get a new context when you got a new message type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that this a particularly satisfactory solution but in the end I took the maps out of the receive port.  My colleague had suggested it was best practice to have that layer of abstraction but in fact that was only relevant for 'classic' BizTalk.

The issue in this particular case appears to be that we have two identical schemas but with different namespaces.  The reason for this being if the external schema changed then we could map to the internal in the port without changing anything else.  Again useful with classic BizTalk as negates changes to orchestration but not really relevant for ESB.